# How to unwrap high number pole on game object

Tags: uv

[image]

I have object with pointy top vertex. As you can see on picture it strecthes if I unwrap it this way. What could be better way, or I should remove this top vertex and make one n-gon. Consider I want this to be hero asset for game, so this top part should be always visible.

Comment: you could create a circular seam all around and simply unwrap, it all depends on your image texture I guess

Comment: Tried but still looks deformed since I want to apply subsurf modifer. I want to export it to substance for texturing so I could maybe hide some seams with substance but still want to understand how to make it best as I could.

Comment: Marking circular seam but deleting this seam which is going to the point vertex fixed it. Feel so stupid now. Thanks :)